# Showing that if two curves are equivalent under a chart then it holds for other every other chart

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Fix $p\in M$. Consider all smooth curves $c : (-\epsilon,\epsilon) \rightarrow M$ with $c(0) = p$. We say that two such curves $c_1$ and $c_2$ are equivalent if there exist some smooth chart $(U,\phi)$ with $p \in U$, such that $$\frac{d}{dt}\phi \circ c_1(0) = \frac{d}{dt}\phi \circ c_2(0).$$I am trying to show that if this is true for some chart, then it must be for every other chart that contains $p$.

**Attempt:** Assume the condition holds for $(U,\phi)$. Pick another chart $(V,\psi)$. Then $\psi \circ \phi^{-1} = \varphi \Leftrightarrow \psi = \varphi \circ \phi$ is smooth on $\psi(U \cap V)$. Thus, \begin{align*}
  \frac{d(\psi \circ c_1)}{dt}(0) & = \frac{d((\varphi \circ \phi) \circ c_1)}{dt}(0)\\
  & = D_{\phi(p)}\varphi \circ D_0(\phi \circ c_1)\\
  & = D_{\phi(p)}\varphi \circ D_{0}(\phi \circ c_2)\\
  & = \frac{d(\varphi \circ (\phi \circ c_2))}{dt}(0)\\
  &= \frac{d(\psi \circ c_2)}{dt}(0).
 \end{align*}

Comment: How are you justifying the third equality?

Comment: My thought was integrating both sides of $\frac{d}{dt}\phi \circ c_1(0) = \frac{d}{dt}\phi \circ c_2(0)$ would yield an equality of smooth functions (composition of smooth functions). But now I am questioning myself about that because it can clearly be different

Comment: @TedShifrin I also thought about using the chain rule! I will edit

Comment: Right. Chain rule it is.

Comment: @TedShifrin May I ask if you could check the details? Thank you very much!

Comment: No, don’t write nonsensical Leibniz derivatives. Write $d\phi_p(v)$, $D\phi_p(v)$, or $D\phi(p)(v)$. Also, it’s important to write $\frac{df}{dt}(0)$, not $\frac d{dt}(f(0))$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Improved! Thank you for the comments

Comment: Why did you evaluate the derivative of $\varphi$ at $\varphi(p)$? That can’t be right!

Comment: @TedShifrin I am evaluating the derivative of $\varphi$ at $\phi(t)$?

Comment: While the intent is clear, your 2nd and 4th equalities are not technically correct, as the Leibnitz derivatives are vectors in tangent spaces, while the expressions between are linear operators between tangent spaces. To make the equalities true, you need to apply those operators to the canonical tangent vector $\frac d{dt} \in T_0\Bbb R$.